# How to monitor disk quota in modern way? Status in widget, menu, status bar?

Tags: xfce, disk-usage, quota

I would like to have constant remainder / status update of remaining disk space within quota set for particular user. I have setting the quotas figured out, just not the monitoring part.

My Ubuntu box is configured to serve multiple users connecting over ssh tunnel and VNC, as multiple users share same hard-disk and quota is set for each user, I would like them to be aware of remaining quota space. I am not sure about all the desktop environments, but in XFCE file manager Thunar is showing remaining disk space and does not show quotas, is there any application for desktop or status bar/notifier for this purpose? These users can not use commands like quota or repquota, because they are not members of sudo group, but also manual command entering does not have preventive character, I also know about possibility of mail notifications, I do not like that idea because e-mail gets the job done only partially and it is not real-time.